# Raising exception on managed and unmanaged callback chain with P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, exception, callback, pinvoke

I am wrapping a native API with P/Invoke calls. For error handling I use the following method:

- Take a callback function from managed code.
- Call this callback function from unmanaged code to indicate an error.
- Throw an exception in the callback.

In other words the flow is like this:

`Managed Method => (P/Invoke) Unmanaged Function => Managed Callback => Throw Exception.`

When I test this method I can catch the exception successfully in the first managed method. But, I'm not 100% sure that this does not cause any side effects on stack or leak memory.

Is it safe to use this method? If not, is there any other method to indicate error (possibly including stack trace) without cluttering the API using P/Invoke?

P.S. I have access to the native code.

Comment: What's the job of the managed callback? If it's sole reason for existence is to raise a manged exception, you should probably consider writing a C++/CLI interop assembly that can, without requiring a managed callback.

Comment: Yes I know of C++/CLI, but the project is started with P/Invoke approach and it will require some amount of work to convert the existing functionality.

Comment: You can continue to use P/Invoke, where you have it, and use a mixed mode interop assembly for new code. Regardless, that didn't quite answer the question I asked.

Comment: It will work, exception handling is unified on Windows and stack unwinding is an OS duty.  Whether the native code *expects* you to throw an exception is however an open question.  Pretty unlikely.  If it is C++ code then it would have to be compiled with /Eha for example, not the default setting.  If it is C code then it has no idea what the heck just happened :)  Memory leaks and state corruption are fairly likely outcomes, gritty because they don't cause instant failure.  Testing this thoroughly is crucial, talk to the author of this code to feel better.   Expect a "no!"

Comment: Thanks. Your comment and [this link](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#runtime-exception-propagation) clear things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it is safe.

Under certain conditions:

- Unmanaged Function can handle SEH exceptions (C++ can, but C can't)
- Unmanaged Function will pass the exception to its caller, so its caller must be able to understand and handle the Managed exception (or pass it upper).

Example, you can't start a new thread and call the managed callback in the new thread, the exception thrown by the callback will certainly terminate you application.

Comment: By new thread do you mean a native thread, a managed thread or both?

Comment: Seems that the first condition should also include that only Visual C++ supports this.

Comment: Both C++ and C can handle SEH exceptions. Neither one provides standard language features to do so. Unless you compile C++ code and instruct the compiler to go non-standard, and allow `catch(...)` to handle SEH exceptions as well (compiler switch `/EHa`).